# Sorting items from plist in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I am having a problem displaying data I am pulling from my "plist" in alphabetical order. This is the line that I am pulling some data from my "plist" and displaying it into my `tableView`.

```
[self.objects addObjectsFromArray:[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle 
mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Climb Data" ofType:@"plist"]] allKeys]];
```

I know in Java it would be something along the lines of `Collections.sort`, but I can't seem to find the equivalent in Objective-C.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: The NSArray documentation has a section "Sorting" ...

Comment: As we know, ```NSDictionary``` is not an ordered data structure. Have you looked into ```keysSortedByValueUsingSelector```?

Comment: Isn't that with comparing 2 objects? How would you compare to see with letters of the alphabet?

Comment: @raurora's suggestion of using `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` would work too, and save you from creating the intermediate, non-sorted array. You'd pass it the compare: or caseInsensitiveCompare: selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do so many things in one line of code. It makes it too hard to figure out and debug. It doesn't make the code any faster, either.

First load the dictionary.

Then load the keys into an array using allKeys.

**THEN** create a sorted version of the array.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Climb Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSArray *keysArray = [dictionary allKeys];
```

The final step is easy:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [keysArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

You could also use `caseInsensitiveCompare:`

There are also methods like `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` that take a comparator block (a block of code you provide) to sort the array. Your block of code is a primitive that compares pairs of objects in your array. The sort method calls your block repeatedly and uses the results of those calls to sort the array.

Comment: hmm I don't know if I quite know how to do the first two steps separately

Comment: How can you not? You know how to make big complex statements but not simpler ones? Are you just copying and pasting code you don't really understand then? In any case, I edited my answer to spoon-feed you step by step code, which I don't like to do.